# running command line in multiple running processes from python

Tags: python, command-line, tcl

I'm not sure if what I'm wanting to do is possible, but:

I have a python script (lets call it PY) that calls a batch script to start a tool in terminal mode (lets call it A). This tool gets passed a starting script (tcl script) that sets up its environment and launches a second tool (lets call it B). The two tools communicate over a TCP connection locally.

My question is, with these two programs running (A and B), can I switch back to the python script to run commands in either A or B's TCL interface?

The scripts look sort of like this:

```
#python PY
def ReadConigAndSetup():
    #read some data
    ...
    #run bat
    subprocess.run("./some_bat.bat some_data_args")
```

---

```
 #bat start program A and pass it a startup script
  some_program_A -mode tcl -source ./some_source.tcl
```

---

```
#tcl some_source.tcl
setup environment

open TCP port
start program B
```

---

```
#program B setup tcl
some more setup
```

after program B has run I'd like to be able to run more commands in program B from python as parsing some of the config files is much easier in the python environment.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is “it depends on the details”.

There's no reason *in principle* why the program being called can't work fine this way, provided the subprocess relinquishes control back (which it might or might not), but launching complex programs via a BAT file is adding an extra layer of complexity so you might want to think about whether you can simplify a bit there.

If the program running the Tcl code doesn't terminate, things get trickier. This is an area where the details are critical; Tcl code can be written to loop indefinitely — it's a programming language so *of course* it can be told to be annoying if you insist — and the program being controlled could also decide to loop indefinitely of its own accord, which can happen particularly with GUI applications as the looping is where the user is interacting with the GUI. On Windows, many GUI applications run disconnected from the terminal (whether they do this is a compile-time option) and waiting for them to finish can be quite annoying.

It's possible to run multiple subprocesses at once using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor). *Be very careful if you do this.* It's possible to get into deadlocks (though that depends a lot on what the subprocesses are doing). It's *probably* easier to just launch each subprocess from its own thread… but then you're dealing with threads and that's also complicated.

Comment: Interacting with running subprocesses is entirely up to how those subprocesses work, and is sufficiently complicated that there are no general rules at all. You'll need narrow things down quite a lot to get a useful answer…

Comment: Yeah having the bat file is annoying, but I can't get A to launch without it. as for keeping both processes alive, A needs to be alive to communicate with B over the TCP connection while B does some setup etc. Both can be killed once B is done. So is it possible to 'point' the python script at the running processes A and B? you mention launching them on their own thread, are there some resources to look into how to achieve and interact with them that way?